# Connecting Tableau and PgPool

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I'm trying to connect Tableau to our database Postgresql via PgPool, for load Balance.

I have Postgresql configured with Streaming Replication between one master and two slaves. And have another server running PgPool for load balance. All of this running correctly for the tests that we've done, I can connect via PgPool from another computer, and even connected some app we have and works fine, PgPool connects with servers with no problem. The thing is, when I try to connect Tableau to my PgPool server i got an Error:

"The connection to the data source might have been lost"

"Communication with the Tableau Protocol Server process was lost"

And checking the logs in my PgPool server I see that it receives the connection, and Tableau does some queries... I guess some to get the tables in the DB, but it says something like:

```
statement:  -- statement does not return rows

 SELECT *

 INTO TEMPORARY TABLE "#Tableau_0_1_Connect"

 FROM (SELECT 1 AS COL) AS CHECKTEMP

 LIMIT 1
```

but I'm guessing it can't get anything... and later Tableau tries to do some cursor:

```
BEGIN;

declare "SQL_CUR00000033237CDCD0" cursor for

select relname, nspname, relkind...."
```

but gets an error:

```
FATAL: unable to Execute

DETAIL: unable to get bind message
```

I don't know if I should configure something else, I'm guessing is some PgPool configuration, but don't know what it can be.

I tried to execute the same exact statements (both of them) in a terminal in another computer and i get rows, with the same user and password, so it's not a privilege thing...

Does anybody know how to solve this or how to use PgPool and Tableau correctly?

Comment: have you checked database permissions for that user to that specific query?  It could also be a result set limit if the result set is too big.

Comment: Hi @kriegu . Yes, like I pointed, i tried the same queries via terminal with the same user and it worked. I'm thinking more of some excecution permission via pgpool but I can't find where it could be.